# Wordpress website is working but wp-admin cannot get any data from database and return 404

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, wp-admin

My website has a problem. Wordpress website is working fine, but every wp-admin/... is return 404, for example:
i can access wp-admin/upload.php but cant load any media.
i can access all wp-admin/plugin but all of them cant load data.
i cannot access wp-admin/page, post, setting, plugin etc, they all return 404 error.

Situation:
website is working fine.

```
domain.com/wp-admin/index.php is working fine.
domain.com/wp-admin/upload.php is working fine but **cant load media images**
domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=[**PLUGIN NAME**] are working fine. but cant load any data eg: wordfence cant load any data on live traffic.
```

==================

```
domain.com/wp-admin/options-general.php is 404
domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page is 404
domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php is 404
domain.com/wp-admin/users.php is 404
domain.com/wp-admin/plugins.php is 404
domain.com/wp-admin/themes.php is 404
domain.com/wp-admin/tools.php is 404
```

all /wp-admin/ page, post, setting, appearance, tools are 404.

i tried disable all plugins, reinstall wordpress, create new htaccess they all not working.

Did anyone can give me suggestion? please help me thank yo so much
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFKWv.png)

i tried disable all plugins, reinstall wordpress, create new htaccess they all not working.